# Run script in loop

Tags: shell, unix

I want to run a unix script from 8 AM till 8 PM continuously in every 5 min of duration.
Tried some of the options but not working.
e.g
first run: @08:00:00
second run: @08:05:00
third run: @08:10:00
.
.
.
Last run: @20:00:00

Comment: _Tried some of the options_  : Options to what?

Comment: HOW did you get your "runs"? By hand?

Answer (score 1):

You could use cron.
This cron syntax should work: */5 8-20 * * *

You can check it [here.](https://crontab.guru/#*/5_8-20_*_*_*)

Edit: in case you are new to cron. You can open your cron file with `crontab -e` and add to it:

```
*/5 8-20 * * * /my/script.sh
```

Comment: I should have specify this before, but I want to achive this without CRON job

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX you may found a problem using `*/5` syntax. So the best you can do is explicitly list all the minutes (and eventually hours):

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 8-20 * * * /path/to/script
```

or with hours:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 * * * /path/to/script
```